# What is the maximum length of Shopify CustomerID in customer response JSON

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Did anyone knows the length of CustomerID field of Shopify Customer JSON, because I want to store the customerID into my database where column length is restricted that I can not change. So I need to know the length.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to save it as a text into DB, so it handles up to a long number, otherwise, it creates issues. in MYSQL I am using `varchar` to resolve the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a predefined length on `CustomerID`, as their resources follow the ActiveRecord pattern of incrementing integers as IDs (for the time being at least). As of now, it's around 12 digits max, but that is growing.

Answer (score 0):

finally I got the Answer from Shopify..

As for the IDs they obviously seem to be **BIGINT**. But that would be wasteful and I seriously cannot imagine Shopify having anticipated gazillions of data rows for the next 1000's of years to come. So what's more likely is that they're composite primary keys which also would make sense given that Shopify surely needs to do some kind of partitioning.

Generally, you will find that most resources follow a **N1 * [10 pow 12, 10 pow 13 - 1]**. Customer and Products are in the N=1 as far as I can tell. Options are in N=2, Images N=5 etc. What's beyond that is anyones guess but probably consists of some kind of composite keys or MMR sequence (among other solutions) to identify the DB within a cluster - for the first part and some random INT key for the actual row. Random as in something like FLOOR(rand() * (max - min) + min) because you don't want curious merchants and app vendors or up-to-no-good black hats to predict stuff e.g.